# Windows Seven Usb Installation Media 32 and 64 Bit

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb

I'd like to make an usb installation media for both windows 7 32 bit and windows 7 64 bit and put into each one all the updates I could find.
I know how to do it with one version of the os 32 bit or 64 bit and all the updates. And get an iso for windows seven 32 bit with all the updates or windows seven 64 bit with all the updates.
But what if I'd like to make bootable usb that asks me what version I would install and then boot the one I want?
I was thinking to use: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/ yumi multi boot usb creator but I don't know if that could work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it.
first follow this guide and get an updated iso for windows seven 32 bit.
https://www.raymond.cc/blog/create-an-integrated-up-to-date-windows-7-install-disc/
then do it again and get an iso for the 64 bit.
then use yumi http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/
first to add the first and then the second iso you made.